# Ansible jinja2 filters '|'(pipe) what does it mean?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have written a task as below but can not understand what '|' does?

```yaml
tasks:
 - shell: /usr/bin/foo
   register: result
   ignore_errors: True

 - debug: msg="it failed"
   when: result|failed

 - debug: msg="it changed"
   when: result|changed
```

Also I have found some examples on web but can not understand what '|' does?

```yaml
debug: msg={{ ipaddr |replace(",", ".") }}
```

One more example:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    D:
      1 : "one"
      2 : "two"
  tasks:
    - debug: var=D
    - debug: msg="D[1] is {{ D[1]|default ('undefined') }}"
```

Would be great if someone can explain in details or point me to some URL?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check the [jinja docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#filters)?

Comment: I saw this in code I'm maintaining and thought, "Python has pipes like shell!?". Thanks for this question to set me straight!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

With the pipe character you pass a value to a filter. There are numerous [Jinja 2 filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#builtin-filters) but Ansible [brings some additional filters](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_filters.html).

The term *filter* might be confusing at times because all the filters work very differently. Some for example reduce a result set of a hash/array, some modify contents of a string, but then there are filters which simply return true or false.

A better explanation might be that those are modifiers and they can do anything with your passed data. You can even [write your own filters](http://docs.ansible.com/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins).

Filters can be chained, passing the result from the first filter to the next and so forth. It works exactly like piping commands on a unix shell.

```
"value" | filter1 | filter2 | filterN
```

The `failed` filter returns `true` if the passed result has failed. It simply checks the `failed` property from `result`.

The `changed` filter is the same, but checks if the passed result has changes. It checks the `changed` property from `result`.

`ipaddr | replace(",", ".")` replaces all occurrences of `,` with `.`. So a value of `127,0,0,1` will be transformed to `127.0.0.1`.

The `default` filter will set a default value if the input was null, e.g. an undefined variable. `undefined_var | default("var was undefined")` -> This will either print the contents of `undefined_var` or the string "var was undefined". In your given example above you output the value of the 2nd element of `D` (`D[1]`) and if it does not exist the sting "undefined" instead.

Comment: Link to Jinja 2 filters is broken.

Answer (score 2):

An update for anyone stumbling across this question trying to work out why lines such as `when: result|failed` has stopped working,

tl;dr: Try replacing `|` with `is` so,

```
when: result|failed
```

becomes,

```
when: result is failed
```

As of Ansible 2.9 and up (*"Using Ansible-provided jinja tests as filters will be [removed in Ansible 2.9.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.5.html#jinja-tests-used-as-filters)"*), using `|` in conditionals such as `when: result|failed` will trigger an error. The `|` is (was) to get Ansible to use a jinja2 *filter*, but these are now replaced with jinja2 *tests*, which have a slightly different syntax, with the old jinja2 *filter* names retained as jinja2 *test* names.

In some cases just replacing `|` with `is` looks a bit weird, so although (e.g.) `when: result is success` is valid, `success` and `successful` are aliases so `when: result is successful` looks better.

More detail on this in the [Ansible 2.5 Porting Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/porting_guides/porting_guide_2.5.html#jinja-tests-used-as-filters).